# How to remove an add-in?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-addin

I've just installed Vuze and it automatically install an add-in in my Outlook 2010 which I want to remove. I try googling of how-to remove it but cannot find a way. Please help.

@jupp66:

I open the add-ins manager, select my add-in to remove, click remove but it open an box that says:

[image]

I close Outlook, right click on the Outlook icon trying to run it as Administrator but I cannot find the menu item allowing me to do so. Please help!

[Edit]
Note to run your Outlook as Administrator by right clicking it and select "Run as Admin...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this page (there is a picture below that shows how to remove Office add-ins):

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/office-outlook-2010-add-in-manager/

If you want to install an add-in manually, hit the Add button and select the add-in that you downloaded. Hitting Remove will remove the add-in.

Answer (score 1):

We use @jupp66 solution above with a note to run your Outlook as Administrator by right clicking it and select "Run as Admin..."